# Templating a generic AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm creating a project template in Visual Studio and I would like to make the AssemblyInfo.cs file a bit more generic. I need the values several times in my project and they are already defined under Resources.resx. Is there any way to (dynamically) build the AssemblyInfo.cs or do I need to hardcode every value?

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Template")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("A simple template")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Sample Company")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Template")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2018")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: Guid("")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("")]
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("")]
```

Comment: Note: if you're using the new .net core csproj build, you a lot of this can be handled via a `Directory.build.props` file, which can be shared between any number of projects by just moving it up/down a folder tree

Answer (score 2):

I would use a linked file, placed outside your projects, where you store the shared properties. Then in a per-project `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, you put all the project-specific properties.

You can link files from the Project Explorer > Add > Existing Item option:

[image]